# Building a SaaS application on Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess, saas

I am on the way of building a SaaS application using Zend Framework on PHP. Here is the basic information of the project. Its Project Management System on SaaS model. When the user registered on the site, they will get a domain name like the format:

user_name.pms.com

user_name - The chosen User Name when the user registered on the Project Management System (pms)

pms.com  - is the main SaaS Server.

Currently we provide the Sub Domain on our Server. And for big firms, it won't look good and they may prefer to get their own domain instead of this default one. So there may be:

user_name.pms.com [Always Present]

user1.com [ The custom or independent domain of the User ] This custom domain needs to link into the default user url.

The full website is planning to develop using Zend Framework.

On Zend Framework, we are having following HTAccess on the root folder for its working and is below:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Here are my questions:

1. Do I really need to create Sub Domain like profile url for all users once they registered on the site ?
2. If it need to create Sub Domains, can PHP check whether the chosen sub domains exists or not and can create Sub Domains from the Script itself ?
3. If there is no need to Sub Domain, can we achieve the same goal using HTAccess in Zend Installation ?
4. Can you provide the HT Access code which does the following:

"user_name1.pms.com" need to redirect to "pms.com"

"user_name1.pms.com/contact"  need to redirect to "pms.com/contact"

ie any request on the Sub Domain like URL must redirect to main website with the format: pms.com followed by Query String.

Very Important:

Important 1:

When I said the redirect to main website, I need to keep the sub domain like URL on the address bar but the request will be served by main website.

ie "user_name1.pms/contact" is going to be served from pms.com/contact but on address bar we still see the url "user_name1.pms/contact"

Important 2:

Whenever we uses the HTAccess to redirect the request to main Zend Server, can I identify the actual url entered on the address bar ie "site1.pms or site1.com" ?

Another Question of Custom Domain Redirection:

The custom domain name like "site1.com" or "site2.com" need to redirect to either:

Option (a): "pms.com"
Option (b): "site1.pms.com

to serve the request. Here also, I need to keep the url on address bar same like the one user entered.

1. Which above option is better (a) or (b) ?
2. Which technology does this work, domain mapping or CName ? Or Any other technology for make this working.

Comment: If you use Apache you can create wildcard alias for your domain then you can check if user exists with php. so you will know if user exists in database you good to go..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sub domains can be handled using some technique in CPanel. To add vurtual sub domains from CPanel, do the steps:

1. Select "CPanel - Sub Domains"
2. Enter star and choose your domain name
3. Choose the directory to which you need to redirect

And handle the redirection from your page.

To develop a SaaS application using Zend, check the tutorial [SaaS application development using PHP in Zend Framework](http://advancedphpsolutions.com/blog/zend-framework/saas-application-development-using-php-in-zend-framework/)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to get you at least near to what you want... but to get all of the way there, you're going to need to get a little more depth.

First of all, your questions:

1. You *may* need to actually set up a whole virtual host for each user, if you intend for them to be able to interact with your site through their own domain.  If you just want them to have their domain redirect to yours that can be done at their registrar (and if they can successfully use masking, which I've always found problematic, it may work completely without doing this.  If you ignore the custom domain requirement, then you can manage subdomains completely through mod_rewrite without having to actually set them up.
2. Probably the best architecture for your site is to proactively set up whatever needs to be set up the moment that the user signs up.  Don't try to do it "just in time" when the user first tries to access it, and therefore it's just as simple as displaying an error when someone, say, types in usre.pms.com rather than user.pms.com.
3. You can use htaccess, or the config file for your site (which is better for performance, but just strictly for "getting done" purposes, htaccess will work fine).
4. [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=ieb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=mod_rewrite%20subdomain%20to%20query%20string&oq=mod_rewrite%20subdomain%20to%20&aq=3v&aqi=g2g-v2&aql=&gs_sm=11&gs_upl=6929l7177l0l10501l3l3l0l0l0l0l70l162l3l3l0&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=5d7b642d94243993&ix=ieb&ion=1&biw=1578&bih=965&pf=p&pdl=300)

Very Important Point #1: this is how mod_rewrite works.  No worries.
Very Important Point #2: yes, so long as you include that information to be passed along in your mod_rewrite rule

Your Last Question of Custom Domain Redirection:

This is where things get complicated.  You can't serve site1.com from pms.com without apache being fully aware that it's looking for site1.com (unless you get forwarding with masking to work without issue at the registrar).  Generally speaking, if you're using forwarding of some sort, then you'll want them to forward to the subdomain, and all will be good completely through mod_rewrite.  If they are directing the domain straight at your server, a CNAME record is probably the right choice, directing to the subdomain, but you'll still have to learn about virtual hosts and how to properly set it up to get everything to work.

I think you may be signing on for more than you realize by letting your clients have their own custom domain.  You can learn how to do what you want with subdomains probably in an afternoon or a couple days tops.  Figuring all of the ins and outs to working with custom domain names could take a lot longer.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. You addressed all questions of mine. Now its my turn to check all these. I will update with my findings soon.